# Setting Up a Python Cron Job

Tags: python, linux, cron

I hope you guys can help. I've never set up a cron job before but would like to run a daily Python script at 5am on my server.

I'm using hosting from CrazyDomains.com.au (Linux server) and can't find any information on how to go about this.

If anyone can recommend a beginners manual on this or has any helpful advice, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your time,
Sam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In command line type `crontab -e` and write this

```
0 5 * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/your/script.py
```

then save the file.
You can check cron jobs list by `crontab -l`.

Quick reference on crontab you can find [here](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference/) or in `man crontab`.